# Mpi4py mpi_test always returns false

Tags: python, mpi, mpi4py

I couldn't find a simmilar question here, so here goes:
Why does the following code always output `(False, None)`? Shouldn't it be `(True, None)`, if the `test()` was called 3 seconds after the process 0 send the message? Also, if I call `req.wait()` before the `test()` i get the output I need, but then it's not non-blockable, so `test()` loses it's purpose (I want to be able to tell that process 1 got a message from any source during those 3 seconds it slept)

Code:

```
import time
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()    

if rank == 0:
    req = comm.isend(0, 1, tag=0);
    req.wait();
elif rank == 1:
    req = comm.irecv();
    time.sleep(3);
    print req.test();
```

Comment: Are you sure this ist the program your are running? There are some `;` that don't belong. What happens if you put `sleep/test` in a loop?

Comment: Weird. If I call the `test` command twice in a row, the second (and any later) output is good. Still, not a normal behavior so if anyone can give me any further instructions, it would be appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am no expert in mpi4py, but assuming it behaves like its MPI C counterpart (which seems like a fair assumption) then indeed, there's little surprise in here.

Well, in fairness, the output of your code is not stated by the MPI standard. What is guaranties is that after **a number** of calls to the `MPI_Test()` function, it will return `true`. This number can be anything, and therefore it return `true` at first call, or at second, or only after one billion calls... Therefore, the usual/recommended way of using the `MPI_Test()` function is to use it here and there, and to finish with either an infinite loop of it (with an exit condition based on its output), or to use a `MPI_Wait()` call.

Now, the reason for that is the following: the MPI library doesn't usually perform any action outside of explicit MPI calls. Therefore, in order to see a non-blocking communication to progress, you have to perform *some* MPI calls. These calls do not need to be related to the standing communications (usually any MPI call will internally trigger some level of progress of the message queue) but you need to give the hand to the MPI library in order to get that. And that's what the calls to `MPI_Test()` do. And that also explains why this isn't really time-related: your call to the `sleep()` function does indeed give time for the communication to happen, but since the MPI library doesn't get the hand in-between, nothing actually happened.

Finally, some moderation to my above explanations:

1. The above supposes no *external* mechanism to progress the in-flight messages. However, (Remote) Direct Memory Access engines, such as those available on InfiniBand cards for example, can indeed progress the messages without having to make extra MPI calls. However, this usually would only happen for inter-node communications and is highly dependent on your hardware and software.
2. Some MPI libraries offer as an extension the possibility to dedicate a CPU thread to progress MPI communication outside of MPI calls. Some MPICH-based MPI libraries, such as Intel MPI for example, propose the `MPICH_ASYNC_PROGRESS` environment variable which, once set to `1`, will trigger the creation of this MPI communication thread to progress non-blocking communications behind the scene. Not sure if OpenMPI proposes this feature as well...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's just because you've created this example from editing down a larger program, but I just wanted to check they're wasn't some underlying misunderstanding of non-blocking MPI comms ...

I don't understand why you have:

```
req = comm.isend(0, 1, tag=0);
req.wait();
```

since this is functionally identical to the blocking call

```
comm.send(0, 1, tag=0);
```

Of course, the non-blocking form means you can later insert more code between isend and wait which is perhaps what you mean to do.

Comment: It is, more or less, it's a test, since I'm new to MPI, the code I've shown in my post runs the way I described it and it's isolated in it's own script.